# how to style a nested react component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that has another nested component inside it. On a particular page I want that component to have a different background color, but it doesn't work. I'm using LESS and importing styles from styles.module.less. What am I doing wrong?

```
<ParentComponent className={styles.parent}>
  <ChildComponent className={styles.child} />
</ParentComponent>

    .parent {
     .child {
      background-color: black;
    }
    }
```

Comment: It should be styles.parent.child but not styles.child

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set style like this?

```
.parent .child {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you can set style in line like this:

```
<ChildComponent style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}} className={styles.child} />
```